# How to get the same output from sphinx napoleon and numpy style docs as with the default rst way?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, numpydoc, sphinx-napoleon

If I take the very simple python file:

```py
def magic_function(parameter1):
    """
    Do magic with parameter1.

    :param parameter1: The first of all paramters
    :type parameter1: nd_array
    """
    return parameter1
```

I get the type right after the parameter:

[image]

If I now use numpy style together with napoleon:

```py
def magic_function(parameter1):
    """
    Do magic with parameter1.

    Parameters
    ==========
    parameter1: nd_array
        The first of all paramters

    """
    return parameter1
```

I end up with this ugly setup

[image]

The issue seems to be that `nd_array` is not a valid type which for the default sphinx does not seem to be a problem, but for napoleon this seems to matter, as for example type `int` works perfectly.

Comment: What version of Sphinx and Napoleon do you use? If you are using an old version, this problem might be fixed in the latest version.

Comment: Sphinx 2.1.1. Which is currently the latest Version on Github. Since Napoleon ships with sphinx, I do not know if there is a separate version of Napoleon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following would work for `nd_array`, but I assume it should as it works for built-in types (`str`,`list`, `float`, etc.). Here is a small example of what works for me:

```
def get_case_id_from_file_name(file_name):
    """ Retrieve case ID from file name.

    Parameters
    ----------
    str file_name
        Name of the test file to retrieve the case ID from.

    Returns
    -------
    list
        A list of split file name with case ID in it.
    """
    return file_name.split('_')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, with valid types it works (see also end of question), just not with descriptive types such as `nd_array`.